# I want to count the elements of a python list that is within a dataframe, and for the output to be a column in the dataframe. How do I do that?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So, I have a data-frame that looks kind of like this:

```
| column_1 | column 2        |
| 0.       | [`a`, 'b', 'c'] |
| 1        | ['z', 'y']      |
| 2        | ['a']           |
```

And the output I want is a column (with the same index numbers) that looks like this:

```
| column_1 | column 2        | column 3|
| 0.       | [`a`, 'b', 'c'] | 3       |
| 1        | ['z', 'y']      | 2       |
| 2        | ['a']           | 1       |
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
df['column_3'] =  df['column_2'].apply(len)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   column_1   column_2  column_3
0         0  [a, b, c]         3
1         1     [z, y]         2
2         2        [a]         1
```

Or a bit more hacky, use the [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html#pandas-series-str) accesor:

```
df['column_3'] = df['column_2'].str.len()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   column_1   column_2  column_3
0         0  [a, b, c]         3
1         1     [z, y]         2
2         2        [a]         1
```